# In a *nix environment, how would I group columns together?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, text-processing, unix

I have the following text file:

```
A,B,C
A,B,C
A,B,C
```

Is there a way, using standard *nix tools (cut, grep, awk, sed, etc), to process such a text file and get the following output:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with `rs(1)` alone, but I can't get it to work as I expect on my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
tr , \\n
```

and that will generate

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

which you could sort.

Unless you want to pull the first column then second then third, in which case you want something like:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) print i, $i}' | sort -sk1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

To explain this, the first part generates

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
1 A
2 B
3 C
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

the second part will stably sort (so the internal order is preserved)

```
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 B
2 B
2 B
3 C
3 C
3 C
```

and the third part will strip the numbers

Answer (score 3):

You could use a shell for-loop combined with cut if you know in advanced the number of columns. Here is an example using bash syntax:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    cut -d, -f $i file.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} /([A-C],)+([A-C])?/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' YOURFILE | sort
```